# Can a function take in equations?

Tags: functions

Is it possible that a function takes in an equation and pops out another equation by modifying the first one like f(2x+2=0)=3x+3=1.

Comment: Sure it's possible. I don't currently see why this would be useful, but it's possible. You just have to strictly define what $f$ does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the broadest sense of the word "function", yes. A function $f:X\to Y$ (or just $f$ or just $X\to Y$ if the rest is understood) consists of three things:

1. a *domain* $X$, which is the set of valid inputs
2. a *codomain* $Y$, which is the set of (potential) outputs
3. an *assignment*, for each element $x$ in the domain a single element $f(x)$ in the codomain

If you have the set of all possible equations as domain, and the set of all possible equations as codomain, then you can define a function between them. There are a *lot* of different possible functions. Most of them cannot be given a finite description in any human language. Some of them can.

For instance, any "rule" you use when solving an equation is such a function. "Add $5$ to both sides" is a concrete example. "Simplify both sides" is also an example, as long as you say *exactly* what you mean by 'simplify', and so are any sub-simplifications like "add together like terms" or "expand parentheses". "Add $3$ to the right side and divide the left side by $4$" is also such a function, although it's not a valid rule when solving equations.

Answer (score 2):

While I can think of no immediate use for a function that takes in an equation and outputs another.. why not? A function $f:A \to B$ is a thing that maps the members of **any** set $A$ to the members of **any** set $B$. As long as the sets $A$ and $B$ are properly defined, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in computeralgebra you obviously do that. i.e. in software like maple/mathematica/sage you can type "simplify(3*x-x=5)" and get $x=5/2$ as a result. But that is more about programming than pure mathematics. The problem is that you have to define what an "equation" actually is. The obvious answer is something like "a word from the alphabet +-*/()=xyz", but you can imagine that won't get you anywhere interesting mathematically.

Actually there are quite interesting results in Computeralgebra about symbolic computing, but that is a very very specialized branch of mathematics, so its probably not what you are after.

On the other hand: A function taking another function as an argument is very common. For example when differentiating you could write:

$D(x\mapsto x^2) = x\mapsto 2x$

And then study the properties of the function $D$